# ARImageTrackingConfiguration.isSupported always returning false

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit

The following attributes are returning `false` for me, but I am not able to understand why.

```
ARImageTrackingConfiguration.isSupported
ARWorldTrackingConfiguration.isSupported
```

I am testing it on a iPhone Xs with iOS 12.1.1, with the code built with Xcode 10.1.

Note that `ARConfiguration.isSupported` does return `true`.

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Answer (score 0):

> Only **one** `ARTracking class` is supported per a given time.

You should write your code this way:

```
import UIKit
import ARKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, ARSCNViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var sceneView: ARSCNView!
    var configuration: ARConfiguration?

    //.........
    //.........

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {        
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)       

        if ARWorldTrackingConfiguration.isSupported {
            configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()         // 6-DoF
        } else {
            configuration = AROrientationTrackingConfiguration()   // 3-DoF
        }
        sceneView.session.run(configuaration!)
    }
}
```

**Also, read carefully about these 3 types of tracking configuration**:

- [ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arworldtrackingconfiguration)  (rotation and translation `x`-`y`-`z`) **6-DoF**
- [AROrientationTrackingConfiguration()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arorientationtrackingconfiguration) (only rotation `x`-`y`-`z`) **3-DoF**
- [ARImageTrackingConfiguration()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arimagetrackingconfiguration) **6-DoF** but image-only tracking lets you anchor virtual content to known images only when those images are in view of the camera.

> Because 3-DoF tracking creates limited AR experiences, you should generally not use the `AROrientationTrackingConfiguration()` class directly. Instead, use the subclass `ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()` for tracking with six degrees of freedom (6-DoF), **plane detection**, and **hit-testing**. Use 3-DoF tracking only as a fallback in situations where 6-DoF tracking is temporarily unavailable.

Hope this helps.